# How to validate Google OAuth token on WebAPI

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, asp.net-core-webapi

I am writing a cross platform C# application, using Avalonia for the front end and a C# WebAPI backend.

I have added a Credetials in Google Console for a Desktop application and am using that ClientID and Client Secret in my client Avalonia App. Here I can successfully obtain UserCredential by calling

```
GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync
```

Now I want to use those credetials to call my WebAPI backend. I last did this with Microsoft and there you just granted the application access to each other in the Azure portal and everything worked. It seems different with google though and I can't tell which of the following 2 approaches I should take

1. Create a Web application Credential and use those ClientId and ClientSecret in the WebAPI and then somehow configure the WebAPI or google to link those two, this is how MS works but I can't figure out how to do that in Google
2. Configure the WebAPI to use JwtBreaer tokens and create a GoogleTokenValidator class manually which calls GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync to do some sort of validation.